# How to integrate Autofac with Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I have follow guide at: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

At last step, it show:

```
// Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
```

However, last version of Asp Net core 2.2, the function ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) is return void

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

How can I refactor my code follow latest change ?

Comment: Just replace `void` with `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Indeed, it worked @John

Answer (score 9):

In your solution you used `void` return type in ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

Actually you can setup and return `IServiceProvider`:

```
public class Startup 
{
  public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

  // ...

  public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    // create new container builder
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // populate .NET Core services
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    // register your autofac modules
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ApiModule());

    // build container
    Container = containerBuilder.Build();

    // return service provider
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(Container);
}
```

See more details in [official documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-1-1-2-2)

Comment: While I was about to post basically the same thing, you might want to add some text to your answer to explain why it works, even if it's just a quote from (and link to) the documentation :)

Comment: This exactly as tutorial from Autofac. The main thing is we can change declare of ConfigService function to return IServiceProvider